# alert once within loop setInterval or requestAnimationFrame, javascript

Tags: javascript

This is an small snipped of a game developed in javascript.

It has a main function that loops infinitely.

**PROBLEM**

I want a single alert to show up when the character dies, otherwise it appears thousands of alerts due to the loop

```
characterDead = false;

function colision(){
//if colision > true
charactedDead = true;
alert("the character died")
}


function main(){
//...other functions
colision();
requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

window.onload = function() {main();};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a characterDead check in `colision()`.

Also, you have a typo - "characte**d**Dead" should be "characte**r**Dead" in the same function :)

```js
var characterDead = false;

function colision() {
  if (!characterDead) { // check if the character is dead already
    characterDead = true; // kill it
    console.log("the character died"); // alert or log this
  }
}


function main() {
  //...other functions
  colision();
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

window.onload = function() {
  main();
};
```

Comment: works terrific my friend thank you. ...you know... javascript world is full of typos!! (thousands of hours lost)

Comment: @Dan You're welcome! I'd suggest use JS linters installed in your editor, it catches issues like these fast and saves a lot of time. I use eslint.